# Rails and Highcharts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm trying to generate a column graph via highcharts using rails.

I have placed the highcharts.js file in the javascript folder and have created my corresponding trials.js file:

```
$(function () {
    new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: { type: 'column', 
                             renderTo: 'trials_chart' },
            title: { text: '' },
            xAxis: { type: 'datetime' },
                yAxis: {
                  title: { text: 'Yield (bales/ha)'}
                },
                series: [{
                name: "",
                  data: [<% @result.each do |d| %>
                                <%= "%.2f" % (d.lint/227) %>
                              <% end %>
                        ]
                                }]
              });
            });
```

Where the data value is i'm trying to pass a loop which isn't working. When i input variables eg. [1,2,3,4,5] it works, but it can't generate and erb requests for some reason. The loop also features in my view to display a table with the data and works fine:

Trials view

```
<table class="table">
<% @result.each do |r| %>
<tr>
<td><%= r.variety.variety_name %></td>
<td><%= "%.2f" % (r.lint/227) %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

My Controller (Trial)

```
def trial
    @result = Result.where('trial_id' => params[:trial_id]).order('lint DESC')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

in controller, try this:

```
def trial
    @result = Result.where('trial_id' => params[:trial_id]).order('lint DESC')
    @data = []
    @result.each do |d|
       @data << ("%.2f" % (d.lint/227)).to_f
    end
    @data = @data.join(", ")
end
```

And then in HighChart script:

```
series: [{
          name: "",
          data: [<%= @data %>]
        }]
```

Thanks.

Comment: No Luck on this method. If I put <%= @data %> in " " then it loads the graph without the data.

Comment: please debug `@data` on `view`.

Comment: Doing a render :text => @data.inspect inside the controller shows the data correctly, e.g. "10.72, 10.12, 9.74" which should make the column graph. It's like rails is having issues rendering the .js but i'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

To make life easier and make your code cleaner I recommend using a library like:

https://github.com/gazay/gon

You can learn more about it and just passing javascript to rails in general
http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript